# Include figure parameters as a callback option - Dash

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I've got a callback function that changes a figure to various spatial maps. When hexbin is selected, I'm aiming to include parameters to alter the figure.

Is it possible to only insert these parameters when the `hexbin` option is selected?

```
import dash
from dash import dcc
from dash import html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.figure_factory as ff


data = pd.DataFrame({
   'Cat': ['t','y','y','y','f','f','j','k','k','k','s','s','s','s'],
   'LAT': [5,6,4,5,4,7,8,9,5,6,18,17,15,16],
   'LON': [10,11,9,11,10,8,8,5,8,7,18,16,16,17],
   })

N = 30
data = pd.concat([data] * N, ignore_index=True)

data['Color'] = data['Cat'].map(dict(zip(data['Cat'].unique(), px.colors.qualitative.Plotly[:len(data['Cat'].unique())])))

Color = data['Color'].unique()

Type_Category = data['Cat'].unique()
Type_cats = dict(zip(Type_Category, Color))


external_stylesheets = [dbc.themes.SPACELAB, dbc.icons.BOOTSTRAP]

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets = external_stylesheets)

filtering = html.Div(children=[
    html.Div(children=[
        html.Label('Cats', style = {'paddingTop': '2rem', 'display': 'inline-block'}),
        dcc.Checklist(
            id = 'Cats',
            options = [
                {'label': 't', 'value': 't'},
                {'label': 'y', 'value': 'y'},
                {'label': 'f', 'value': 'f'},
                {'label': 'j', 'value': 'j'},
                {'label': 'k', 'value': 'k'},
                {'label': 's', 'value': 's'},
            ],
            value = ['t', 'y', 'f', 'j', 'k', 's'],
        ),

        html.Label('Type', style = {'paddingTop': '2rem', 'display': 'inline-block'}),
        dcc.RadioItems(['Scatter', 'Heatmap', 'Hexbin'], 'Scatter', 
                       inline = True, id = 'maps'),

        html.Label('Opacity', style = {'paddingTop': '2rem', 'display': 'inline-block'}),
        dcc.Slider(0, 1, 0.1,
               value = 0.5,
               id = 'my-slider'),

        html.Label('nx_hexagon', style = {'paddingTop': '2rem', 'display': 'inline-block'}),
        dcc.Slider(0, 40, 5,
               value = 20,
               id = 'my-slider'),

        html.Label('min count', style = {'paddingTop': '2rem', 'display': 'inline-block'}),
        dcc.Slider(0, 5, 1,
               value = 0,
               id = 'my-slider'
    ),
    ],
    )
])

app.layout = dbc.Container([
    dbc.Row([
        dbc.Col([
            html.Div(filtering),
        ], width = 2),
        dbc.Col([
            html.Div(dcc.Graph())
            ]),
        dbc.Col([
            html.Div(dcc.Graph(id = 'chart'))
            ])
    ])
], fluid = True)

df = data

@app.callback(
    Output('chart', 'figure'),
    [Input("Cats", "value"),
    Input("maps", "value")])

def scatter_chart(cats,maps):

    if maps == 'Scatter':

        dff = df[df['Cat'].isin(cats)]
        data = px.scatter_mapbox(data_frame = dff,
                                 lat = 'LAT',
                                 lon = 'LON',
                                 color = 'Cat',
                                 color_discrete_map = Type_cats,
                                 zoom = 3,
                                 mapbox_style = 'carto-positron',
                                )

        fig = go.Figure(data = data)

    elif maps == 'Heatmap':

        dff = df[df['Cat'].isin(cats)]

        # Creating 2-D grid of features
        [X, Y] = np.meshgrid(dff['LAT'], dff['LON'])

        Z = np.cos(X / 2) + np.sin(Y / 4)

        fig = go.Figure(data =
           go.Densitymapbox(lat = dff['LON'],
                            lon = dff['LAT'],
                            z = Z,
                            )
                    )

        fig.update_layout(mapbox_style = "carto-positron")

    else:

        dff = df[df['Cat'].isin(cats)]

        fig = ff.create_hexbin_mapbox(data_frame = dff, 
                                      lat = "LAT", 
                                      lon = "LON",
        )

    return fig

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True, port = 8051)
```

Intended output when `hexbin` is selected:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just use slider value as Input and then when you choosing Hexbin, you can pass it to graph setting. Something as below:

```
import dash
from dash import dcc
from dash import html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.figure_factory as ff

data = pd.DataFrame({
    'Cat': ['t', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'f', 'f', 'j', 'k', 'k', 'k', 's', 's', 's', 's'],
    'LAT': [5, 6, 4, 5, 4, 7, 8, 9, 5, 6, 18, 17, 15, 16],
    'LON': [10, 11, 9, 11, 10, 8, 8, 5, 8, 7, 18, 16, 16, 17],
})

N = 30
data = pd.concat([data] * N, ignore_index=True)

data['Color'] = data['Cat'].map(
    dict(zip(data['Cat'].unique(), px.colors.qualitative.Plotly[:len(data['Cat'].unique())])))

Color = data['Color'].unique()

Type_Category = data['Cat'].unique()
Type_cats = dict(zip(Type_Category, Color))

external_stylesheets = [dbc.themes.SPACELAB, dbc.icons.BOOTSTRAP]

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets,suppress_callback_exceptions=True)

app.layout = dbc.Container([
    dbc.Row([
        dbc.Col([html.Label('Cats', style={'paddingTop': '2rem', 'display': 'inline-block'}),
                 dcc.Checklist(
                     id='Cats',
                     options=[
                         {'label': 't', 'value': 't'},
                         {'label': 'y', 'value': 'y'},
                         {'label': 'f', 'value': 'f'},
                         {'label': 'j', 'value': 'j'},
                         {'label': 'k', 'value': 'k'},
                         {'label': 's', 'value': 's'},
                     ],
                     value=['t', 'y', 'f', 'j', 'k', 's'],
                 ),

                 html.Label('Type', style={'paddingTop': '2rem', 'display': 'inline-block'}),
                 dcc.RadioItems(['Scatter', 'Heatmap', 'Hexbin'], 'Scatter',
                                inline=True, id='maps'),
                 html.Div(id='filter')
                 ], width=2),
        dbc.Col([
            html.Div(dcc.Graph())
        ], width=5),
        dbc.Col([
            html.Div(dcc.Graph(id='chart'))
        ], width=5)
    ])
], fluid=True)

df = data


@app.callback(
    Output('filter', 'children'),
    [Input("maps", "value")])
def update_slider(maps):
    if maps == 'Hexbin':
        return html.Div([html.Label('Opacity', style={'paddingTop': '2rem', 'display': 'inline-block'}),
                         dcc.Slider(0, 1, 0.1,
                                    value=0.5,
                                    id='my-slider'),

                         html.Label('nx_hexagon', style={'paddingTop': '2rem', 'display': 'inline-block'}),
                         dcc.Slider(0, 40, 5,
                                    value=20,
                                    id='my-slider2'),

                         html.Label('min count', style={'paddingTop': '2rem', 'display': 'inline-block'}),
                         dcc.Slider(0, 5, 1,
                                    value=0,
                                    id='my-slider3'
                                    )])
    else:
        return html.Div([html.Div(id='my-slider'),
                         html.Div(id='my-slider2'),
                         html.Div(id='my-slider3')])


@app.callback(
    Output('chart', 'figure'),
    [Input("Cats", "value"),
     Input("maps", "value"),
     Input("my-slider", "value"),
     Input("my-slider2", "value"),
     Input("my-slider3", "value")],prevent_initial_call=True)
def scatter_chart(cats, maps, my_slider, my_slider2, my_slider3):
    if maps == 'Scatter':

        dff = df[df['Cat'].isin(cats)]
        data = px.scatter_mapbox(data_frame=dff,
                                 lat='LAT',
                                 lon='LON',
                                 color='Cat',
                                 color_discrete_map=Type_cats,
                                 zoom=3,
                                 mapbox_style='carto-positron',
                                 )

        fig = go.Figure(data=data)
        return fig
    elif maps == 'Heatmap':

        dff = df[df['Cat'].isin(cats)]

        # Creating 2-D grid of features
        [X, Y] = np.meshgrid(dff['LAT'], dff['LON'])

        Z = np.cos(X / 2) + np.sin(Y / 4)

        fig = go.Figure(data=
                        go.Densitymapbox(lat=dff['LON'],
                                         lon=dff['LAT'],
                                         z=Z,
                                         )
                        )

        fig.update_layout(mapbox_style="carto-positron")
        return fig
    elif maps == 'Hexbin':
        dff = df[df['Cat'].isin(cats)]
        try:
            fig = ff.create_hexbin_mapbox(data_frame=dff,
                                          lat="LAT",
                                          lon="LON",
                                          opacity=my_slider,
                                          nx_hexagon=my_slider2,
                                          min_count=my_slider3)

            fig.update_layout(mapbox_style="open-street-map")
            return fig
        except TypeError:
            pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True, port=8051)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This works well. Is it possible to _hide_ the sliders until `hexbin` is selected? Ideally, I add parameters to the Heatmap and scatter.

Comment: Thanks but I'm getting a few errors. `Attempting to connect a callback Input item to component:
  "my-slider3"`

Comment: @jonboy: Oh problem is that I use Jupyter Notebook and `debug = False` and did not see the errors. I edited my answer. Please check it.

Comment: Thanks, errors are now gone and the map transitions between `scatter` and `heat map`. While the `hexbin`parameters appear when executing the button, the spatial map does not change to a `hexbin` though.

Comment: Hm can you recheck it? It working well for me.

Comment: Weird. It works sometimes but can get _stuck_. But if I refresh the page it works again. Thanks for this.